# Interface with Invalid variance

Tags: .net

I cant understand why this wont compile, I have a interface which I'm trying to convert to async

Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'IFoo.WontWork()'. 'T' is covariant.

```
    public class Bar
    {

    }

    public interface IFoo<out T> where T : Bar
    {
        Task<T> WontWork();
    }
```

However this is Valid

```
     public class Bar
    {

    }

    public interface IFoo<out T> where T : Bar
    {
        T DoesWork();
    }
```

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? `Task<T>` is a type and `Bar` doesn't implement it. You can't output `Task<T>` just as you couldn't output `List<T>`, `HashSet<T>` or any other collection of `T`, because `Bar` doesn't implement any of those. For the second example, `Bar` is `Bar`, so the code is fine.

Comment: IFoo is used in another Service, which should return Bar as a Result, so Bar doesnt need to implement any interface

Comment: Yes, I'm definitely misunderstanding something, Bar is just a return type of the Function "WontWork" I dont see why it needs to implement anything?

Comment: No, `Bar` is not the return type of `WontWork`, `Task<T>` is the return type of `WontWork`. My point was not that `Bar` should implement `Task<T>`. My point was that `Task<T>` is a class. `Bar` is a different class. Unless `Bar` implements `Task<T>`, you cannot return `Task<T>` in the place of `Bar`.

Comment: So is it not possible to do a Async method in this manner?. I could change to this which compiles, but in my case Bar class is abstract.

```
    public interface IFoo<out T> where T : Bar
    {
        Task<Bar> DoesWork();
    }
```